# Why is this Linq to Entities query so slow when actually running in website

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2012, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core

I have a website that gets data using Linq-to-entities.

Most of the time it works fine, but in this case, the query takes from 6 to 30 seconds when actually running as part of the website on Azure.

But this makes no sense.  When I run the website on my dev machine, the Debug window tells me that it takes 126 milliseconds.  So why the vast difference when actually running in production.

Executing the query in SSMS takes about 3 seconds. It is getting a very small amount of data, and it's not very complex, so it really should be sub-second.

This is the query as reported by the Debug Window against sql server:

```
FrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (126ms) [Parameters=[@__ef_filter__CurrentTenantId_0='?' (DbType = Int32), @__parentId_0='?' (DbType = Int32), @__entityStatusId_1='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [b].[Id], [b].[AssignedToId], [b].[BaselineEndDate], [b].[BaselineStartDate], [b].[Budget], [b].[CloseDate], [b].[CloseStatusId], [b].[Cost], [b].[Description], [b].[Details], [b].[DueDate], [b].[Duration], [b].[EntityStatusId], [b].[ImportanceTypeId], [b].[Inserted], [b].[InsertedBy], [b].[ItemTypeId], [b].[Name], [b].[Note], [b].[OwnedById], [b].[ParentId], [b].[Predecessor], [b].[PriorityTypeId], [b].[Progress], [b].[Risk], [b].[SortOrder], [b].[StartDate], [b].[StatusTypeId], [b].[TenantId], [b].[TimeEstimate], [b].[TimeScaleTypeId], [b].[Updated], [b].[UpdatedBy]
FROM [Items] AS [b]
LEFT JOIN [PriorityTypes] AS [a.PriorityType] ON [b].[PriorityTypeId] = [a.PriorityType].[Id]
INNER JOIN [ItemTypes] AS [a.ItemType] ON [b].[ItemTypeId] = [a.ItemType].[Id]
WHERE ([b].[TenantId] = @__ef_filter__CurrentTenantId_0) AND (([b].[ParentId] = @__parentId_0) AND ([b].[EntityStatusId] = @__entityStatusId_1))
ORDER BY [a.ItemType].[SortOrder], CASE
    WHEN [b].[SortOrder] IS NOT NULL
    THEN 0 ELSE 1
END, [b].[SortOrder], CASE
    WHEN [b].[PriorityTypeId] IS NOT NULL
    THEN 0 ELSE 1
END, CASE
    WHEN [b].[PriorityTypeId] IS NOT NULL
    THEN [a.PriorityType].[SortOrder] ELSE 1000000
END, [b].[Name]
```

This is the linq:

```
IQueryable<Item> query =
                this.DbContext.Items
                .OrderBy(a => a.ItemType.SortOrder).
                ThenBy(a => a.SortOrder != null ? 0 : 1).  //First, Put Non-Nulls at the top before nulls
                ThenBy(a => a.SortOrder). //Now Sort the non-nulls by SortOrder
                ThenBy(a => a.PriorityTypeId != null ? 0 : 1). //First put the non-null Priority Type at the top before nulls
                ThenBy(a => a.PriorityType != null ? a.PriorityType.SortOrder : 1000000). //Now Sort by Priority Type
                ThenBy(a => a.Name)
                .Where(a => a.ParentId == parentId && a.EntityStatusId == entityStatusId);
```

To speed this up I have tried increasing the service level of SQL Server, as well as the service level of the website to expensive version, but it made no difference as the very cheapest versions.

Any performance enhancing tips would be appreciated (no steroids, however).

**Update**
I was able to improve the performance dramatically by using a Select, which selects a subset of the data:

```
IQueryable<ChildItemInfo> query = 
                this.DbContext.Items
                .OrderBy(a => a.ItemType.SortOrder).
                ThenBy(a => a.SortOrder != null ? 0 : 1).  //First, Put Non-Nulls at the top before nulls
                ThenBy(a => a.SortOrder). //Now Sort the non-nulls by SortOrder
                ThenBy(a => a.PriorityTypeId != null ? 0 : 1). //First put the non-null Priority Type at the top before nulls
                ThenBy(a => a.PriorityTypeId != null ? a.PriorityType.SortOrder : 1000000). //Now Sort by Priority Type
                ThenBy(a => a.Name)
                .Where(a => a.ParentId == parentId && a.EntityStatusId == entityStatusId).
                Select(i => new ChildItemInfo() { 
                    Id = i.Id,
                    AssignedToName = i.AssignedToId != null ? i.AssignedTo.ApplicationUser.FullName : null,
                    OwnedByName = i.OwnedBy.ApplicationUser.FullName, 
                    Budget = i.Budget,
                     CloseDate = i.CloseDate,
                     CloseStatusName = i.CloseStatus !=null ? i.CloseStatus.Name : "",
                     ItemTypeId = i.ItemTypeId,
                     ItemTypeIcon = i.ItemType.Icon,
                     ImportanceTypeDescription = i.ImportanceType != null ? i.ImportanceType.Description: "",
                     EntityStatusId = i.EntityStatusId,
                     DueDate = i.DueDate,
                     Cost = i.Cost,
                     ItemTypeShowProperties = i.ItemType.ShowProperties,
                     ItemTypeSortOrder = i.ItemType.SortOrder,
                     PriorityTypeDescription = i.PriorityType != null ? i.PriorityType.Description : "",
                     ParentId = i.ParentId,
                     Name = i.Name,
                     PriorityTypeId = i.PriorityTypeId,
                     Progress = i.Progress,
                     SortOrder = i.SortOrder,
                     StartDate = i.StartDate,
                     StatusTypeName = i.StatusType.Name,
                     TimeEstimate = i.TimeEstimate,
                     TimeScaleTypeName = i.TimeScaleType.Name
                });
```

Comment: After your update: that probably means that you significantly narrowed down the width of the result set. The performance effect of that is often underestimated. Or did the original `SELECT` contain computed columns? Also: can't you remove the 4th order by clause? The 5th clause implies it.

Comment: @GertArnold, good point on the order by clauses. Yes, the width of the result set was reduced quite a bit by using the select.  I was careful to only select the required fields.  I am not entirely sure what you mean by computed columns. There are `includes`, but I don't think there are any computed columns.

Comment: If the original query was returning Entities from the context query you were probably getting caught out by lazy loading when MVC went to serialize the results. For best performance, select view models to return to the views rather than returning entities. This ensures that the SQL is optimized for just the data needed, and MVC doesn't trip up lazy loading when serializing. You can confirm serialization by putting a breakpoint prior to the call function returning, then watching an SQL profiler after the function exits. Lazy loads will show as multiple SELECT TOP 1's after function exits.